# Contacts not loading when user select send a Mailing using Tridion 2011 SP1 Outbound email

Tags: 2011-sp1, outbound-email, audience-manager

Contacts not loading when user select send a Mailing using Tridion 2011 SP1 Outbound email.

- Created New Publication and given Mailing Execution Rights and Given Read and Write Permissions to Distrbution List and Mailing List Folders .
- Able to Send Test Email with single email
- When we click on Send a Mailing , the distribution list contains two contacts but it does not load under Number of e-mails to send and
- did the configuration based on the document.
- The contact is there on Tridion_cm_email DB on CM and on the Delivery we see that on the Tridion_submng DB , did a query under extended_contants_detail table.

Please let us know  how to trouble shoot this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible reasons you cannot send the Mailing to those Contacts:

1. The Contacts do not have the minimum subscription status selected on the Mailing (e.g. the Mailing requires 'opted-in' but they only have 'subscribed')
2. The Contacts are set to only accept plain text e-mails and your Mailing (templates) only has an HTML version.
3. The combination of Address Books and Distribution Lists on the Mailing do not contain those Contacts (e.g. they are in a different Address Book).
4. You have already sent this Mailing to those Contacts. A Mailing can only be sent to a Contact once, ever.

Comment: Thanks peter. 1) I will check the min status, i just created two contacts with status default to subscribed, do you want me to change the status to opt-in an try. 2) when we click on sent to mailing , will try to select only html, i did try that when I sent the test email and it worked. 3) Yes we have seperate address book , 4) No I have not sent , when I click on send it says  are you sure you want to send email to (0) emails.

Comment: #1 is probably the most likely cause in your case. Contacts are subscribed by default (and opt-in when you send them a confirmation e-mail with a link to opt in) -- and Mailings only send to opted-in Contacts by default. This is a good practice, as you don't want to be sending e-mails to people who haven't asked for it. So yes, for your test it's best to manually opt-in on the Contacts and leave the Mailing as it is.

Comment: I made the contacts set to opt in manually and now I see the contacts loading successfully.

Comment: peter, for test its fine we set the contact to Opt-in , but i am not sure why the contacts are not  picked up , the strange part is we have two more publication when business user imports the contact and by default the contacts are set to subscribed and the contact loads successfully, recently created new publication and created new address book for this publication and mailing , distribution but not sure why its not loading the contacts when we click on Send a Mailing. Let me know how to troubleshoot this issue. Business will import 1000 of contacts they don't set any status when they upload.

Comment: As I have already explained, you either change the requirements in your Mailings -- or you change the Contacts to match those requirements. So clearly, if they import Contacts and never change their subscription status, they must have changed the Mailings to send to people who have only subscribed but not opted in.

Comment: Thanks peter, so when business imports the contacts it will be set to subscribed by default and when creating a mailing the business user should do the following to load the contacts, correct me if I am wrong,By default, e-mails are sent to all Contacts who have confirmed their subscription (opted-in). In theSubscription Status field, you can also choose to send e-mails to Contacts with a different subscription status: Select the Have shown interest check box to send to Contacts who have indicated interest (opted-in or subscribed but have not confirmed).

Comment: it worked Select the Have shown interest check box to send to Contacts who have indicated interest (opted-in or subscribed but have not confirmed).

Comment: Yes, that will work. Of course you shouldn't be sending e-mails to people who have not opted in (could be illegal, depending on which country they live in) so I would hope that they *have* actually opted-in to receive e-mails before you do so. If that is true, I would actually recommend that you instead change the Contact subscription status as you import them (you can set that field to a fixed value instead of mapping it to a column in the file)